# Cant seem to execute function passed to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, semantic-ui, aurelia

This is a jQuery plugin I'm trying to run.  More specifically, it's one of Semantic Ui's widgets that I'm trying to leverage in Aurelia in an ES 6/7 environment that is transpiled.

This works:

```
return $(this.element)[this.methodTrigger]();
```

but this does not:

```
let trigger = $(this.element)[this.methodTrigger];
return trigger();
```

where `$(...)` is a jQuery selector and `this.methodTrigger` is just a string, like "rating" to load the Semantic UI rating widget

Am I doing something wrong? Is this something that isn't allowed in ES6? Is it transpiling down to plain JS incorrectly? Am I being brain dead and not seeing something really obviously wrong?

Syntax wise it looks like it should work...

Comment: What do you mean it "isn't working?" My guess is that the `this` is incorrect. Calling `trigger()` uses the global scope or `undefined` as `this`.

Comment: the first section works, and it displays the widget properly on screen.  the second section does nothing, no widget, but no errors on console.

Comment: Open your console (hit F12). Do you see any errors? My guess is you'll see something like `Cannot read property 'prop' of undefined`.

Comment: I would have though I'd see _something_ in the console, but nothing.  The second part just executes as if nothing happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value is expecting `this` to reference a jQuery object but by assigning the function to a variable before invoking it, you're losing the calling context. This means it's being called as though it were a global function. You can manually set the context using [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
let $this = $(this.element);
let trigger = $this[this.methodTrigger].bind($this);
```

Comment: That did the trick :).  Need to be a little more vigilant with my `this` context.